# Fully qualified static member definition won't compile

Tags: c++

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        B(int);
    };
}

namespace C
{
    class D
    {
        static const ::A::B b;
    };
}

const ::A::B ::C::D::b(0);      // #1
// const ::A::B C::D::b(0);     // #2
// const ::A::B (::C::D::b)(0); // #3
```

Option #1 fails to compile.  Now that I've thought about it for a while, I'm pretty sure the compiler considers the whitespace between "B" and "::C" insignificant, so it is trying to find a member "C" inside "B".  If that's what's happening, I need some way to convince the compiler that these are two separate qualified names.

Options #2 and #3 both seem to work in a very minimal test.  #3 seems somewhat less vulnerable to name collisions since it's more qualified.  #3 is also somewhat easier for me to switch to.  So I lean towards #3, but it looks weird.

*Is there any strong reason to prefer one over the other?  Can I expect both to work correctly on other compilers?  Is there an even better solution than either one?  And for that matter, am I correct about why #1 fails?*

**Probably unnecessary details**

- The code that inspired this question was output by a source code generator I wrote.  The identifiers are derived from the generator's input, so I'm concerned about name collisions, specifically unintentional shadowing between scopes, which the generator can't detect.  So, I wrote the generator to qualify every identifier as fully as possible.
- I'm compiling on VC2010.
- I'm intentionally *not* using C++0X features, as I want the code to be portable to certain older compilers.
- The specific compiler error is "error C3083: 'C': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type"

Comment: **Related:** http://kera.name/articles/2011/02/befriending-your-parser/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the compiler considers the whitespace between "B" and "::C" insignificant, so it is trying to find a member "C" inside "B"

That's precisely correct.

> Is there any strong reason to prefer one over the other? Can I expect both to work correctly on other compilers?

Option #3 looks fine to me (and is compliant); that is, if you're *really* stuck with this rather silly-looking requirement. :)

I use it myself to conclude [a blog post on a very similar "issue"](http://kera.name/articles/2011/02/befriending-your-parser/).

Comment: Thanks.  The full qualification isn't a requirement so much as a "safe" default.  There are some other places in the generated code where some qualification is needed to get around shadowing.  It was easier to generate the fully qualified name everywhere than it would have been to selectively qualify only certain things.  If excessive qualification causes me any more problems, I'll probably reconsider, but for now, I think I'm still satisfied with the tradeoffs.  Of course, that's only for generated code; I generally don't unnecessarily qualify anything in code I write by hand.